# Cannot Leave a Review about an Extension Installed at Magento Marketplace?

Tags: extensions, review

Yesterday, one of our customers said that she downloaded our extension on Magento Marketplace only to find that she cannot leave a review after finding our app really works. So she asks me for help.

However, I have no idea how this review process works either. Does anyone here know how to leave a review about one extension you installed at Magento Marketplace?

This is very important for me to know how we can make improvements to our extensions.